# reference index subtable distribution

Tags: teradata

I am aware of the fact that maintaining the reference index subtable has similar overhead to USI subtable.

What I am trying to understand is that what kind distribution would it have. My guess is that it will be on basis of the PRIMARY KEY of the REFERENCED table.

Would like to know more on this please.